# Setting up a Restful POST request using xml

Tags: java, xml, rest

I'm working on setting up a RESTful request for the application I'm working on and I wanted to use xml as the request in the uri instead of allowing the client to supply the parameters in the URI itself.

I'm looking to have the URI like so: someurl/service/request

instead of:  someurl/service/request?id={id}&name={name}

I have been searching the web to see what the convention should be when creating the POST request.  Can anyone kind of help point me in the right direction on how I should set up this POST request allowing the client to use xml?

Not sure if it is relevant but I'm setting up the server side code in JAVA using the SPRING 3.0 framework.  Please let me know if I need to supply more details.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: According to HTTP specification you can specify parameters in POST request, but if you want to POST XML file, then it's upto how this file looks like, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put parameters into the body of the request. They are the same format as appending them to the URL. Eg:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
```

You can do that in prototype pretty easily with:

```
new Ajax.Request('someurl/service', {
method: 'post',
postBody: 'home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies',
encoding: 'UTF-8'});
```

To add your xml file, just append it to your postBody with some sort of delimiter so your cgi knows where parameters end and where xml begins.

I think that's what you were looking for, hope it helps.

Comment: If you wanted to send a full XML document only, that's fine too...  Just replace the `postBody` with your XML data.  It would probably be a good idea to change the content type in that case, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whatever you want in your `POST` body.  So if you want to use XML, you can use XML.  Example:

```
POST /car
Content-Type: text/xml
<car>
   <date>10-10-2007<date>
   <type>Corvette</type>
</car>

HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
```

I think all the REST API frameworks let you easily specify XML in the client request and server response.  See Restlet's [quick start](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/firstResource) for an example.